# How to use a reverse proxy (provided by others) on PC

Tags: windows, dns, reverse-proxy

Stack Exchange uses some scripts from ajax.googleapis.com. However that domain is blocked by China Communist Party, so every time I visit a site it shows a red banner that reads "Super User requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load".

Fortunately, I found a Chinese website that offers mirrors to numerous widely-known repositories, and it's providing **reverse proxy** for ajax.googleapis.com. That site has no documents for reverse proxy, and they only provided a domain and tells me it's its RP available to the public.

That reverse proxy seems to be intended for site developers, so a dev can change all ajax.googleapis.com to ajax.proxy.example.com in his pages.

I want to configure my Windows PC and a Linux system to use that RP whenever Google Ajax is requested. I've Googled around without finding anything about using on a PC (use RP from the client side). Or alternatively change all `ajax.googleapis.com` to `ajax.proxy.example.com`. How can I do that?

> For details, please assume the site gave me `ajax.googleapis.com → ajax.proxy.example.com` and its IP is 12.34.56.78.

Answer (score 0):

There are browser extensions to use specific proxies when the URL matches a specific regular expression. On Firefox I use FoxyProxy for this.

Comment: However I use Google Chrome.

Comment: There is a Chrome version of FP. And there may be other add-ons with similar functionality.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is wrong. I've played around with FP and haven't been able to find a way to set a custom server.